# Using Django ORM get_or_create with multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Django's ORM supports querying from a specific database (when multiple are defined in your project) via the .using() function for filter-based operations.

e.g. `MyModel.objects.filter(name='Bob').using('my_non_default_database')`

How would you do the equivalent when creating new records, via the class MyModel() or shortcut like get_or_create()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`using` is a method on the `MyModel.objects` manager, so you can do

```
MyModel.objects.using('my_non_default_database').get_or_create(name="Bob")
```

If you have a MyModel instance, you can use the using keyword to specify the database to save to. The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save) point out some gotchas.

```
my_model = MyModel(name="Bob")
my_model.save(using='my_non_default_database')
```

Comment: How is it handled for regular model creation? e.g. MyModel(name='bob')

Comment: Saving has a keyword argument `using`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`using` is just part of the standard query chain. So, you can use it anywhere before the query is sent to the DB. `get_or_create`, unlike `filter`, is atomic: when you call it, it does it's thing immediately, so you just need to call `using` before that.

```
MyModel.objects.using('my_non_default_database').get_or_create(name='Bob')
```